# Blazor - Navigating to a different page

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I would like to learn a bit about Blazor, so I'm making a simple website using a Blazor Minimal Project Template (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.BlazorMinimalProjectTemplate).

I created a *Pages* folder, in which I have *About.razor* and *Index.razor*

In the About.razor I only have:

```
@page "/about"

<h3>About</h3>
```

I would like to be able to go from index page to about page. I'm trying to achieve this with a simple link in *Index.razor*:

```
<a href="About">About</a>
```

Unfortunately, this only changes the URL from *localhost:1111* to *localhost:1111/About* but the page doesn't change (it's still the index page).

Even if I write the URL (/about), I'm still on the index page.

What's the best way to navigate to a different page using Blazor?

Comment: The `MyApp.razor` has a `DefaultLayout="@typeof(Index)"` try changing it to `DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout)` and create a layout for your pages in a folder called `Shared`. An empty layout is fine as long as you have `@Body` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the template you selected is very minimal!

HMZ has the right idea.  For your reference, I tried this and it worked for me.

**Layout.razor (new file stored in Shared Folder)**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MyApp.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using BlazorMinimal1.Shared

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

IMO, If you are trying to learn about Blazor you might be better off using the standard templates provided in Visual Studio.